# Apache configuration override for subdirectories

Tags: regex, apache, caching

I want to change the caching properties of a subfolder but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Instead of files in foo/images and foo/icons being cached, they are returned with no-cache set.

```
# enable caching for static files
<Directory ~ "^/web/foo/(images|icons)">
    ExpiresActive On
    # cache images and media for 7 days
    ExpiresDefault A604800
    Header append Cache-Control "public, proxy-revalidate"
</Directory>

<Directory ~ "^/web/(foo|bar)">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A0
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</Directory>
```

I basically want everything to not cache unless they are in certain subfolders. My understanding was that Directory with regex matches would match in the order listed.

Keep in mind that my real website is much more complex than this fake example. So yes, I know I could set the default to not cache and then set it per directory, but I can't actually do that on this configuration, so I want to do this with only Directory directives and also no .htaccess files.

Comment: Is it only the `Pragma` header you see (Will always be set btw)? Or is it the `Cache-Control` as well?

Comment: It looks like both of these directives are run for the subfolders, so for Cache-Control you end up with `no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, no-transform, public, proxy-revalidate`

Comment: Did you try my suggestion in the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that both `<Directory ~ "..">` settings are valid. This will make the less specific one (`^/web/(foo|bar)`) overwrite the changes you made in the `images` and `icons` directory. You could try excluding these directories from the parent `Directory`.

```
<Directory ~ "^/web/(foo|bar)(?!(/icons|/images))">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A0
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</Directory>
```

Hope it helps you foward.